# Creating a Function to make cin only allow numbers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    cout << "Enter an int: ";
    int x = 0;
    while(!(cin >> x))
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
    }
    cout << "You entered: " << x << endl;        
}
```

I want to create a simple function out of this code.
So i did the following. But it will obviously run cin twice how do i make it so it only uses cin once?

```
void nInput(int x)
{

//cout << "Enter an int: ";
int y = 0;
while (!(cin >> y)) 
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
}
cout << "You entered: " << y << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    cout << "Enter an int:  ";
    cin >> a;
    nInput(a);
}
```

i tried changing the

```
 while (!(cin >> y))
```

to

```
 while (!(x >> y))
```

But it doesn't really work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Literally remove `cin >> y` in main, make `nInput` take a reference and inside replace `y` with `x`.

Comment: I'm *almost* tempted to close this as a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31645524/179910

Comment: I flagged as off-topic, because as someone noted in the comments, it seems to be a typographic error, or something small enough not to benefit other users. Even your question title denotes a method you created, rather than the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `x` inside of `nInput()`, so there is no point in calling `cin >> a` before calling `nInput()`, so just remove it.  If you don't want `cin` called twice, then don't call it twice to begin with:

```
int nInput()
{
    cout << "Enter an int:  ";
    int y = 0;
    while (!(cin >> y)) 
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
    }
    cout << "You entered: " << y << endl;
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    int a = nInput();
    // use a as needed...
}
```